# How exactly Eclipse Code-Completion works?? What Algorithm they are using?

Tags: eclipse, code-completion, code-assist

Can Anyone tell me how the code completion(or code assist whatever is preferable) in Eclipse works?? I mean the tricks/algorithms/Data-Structures it is using.. Somewhere I found that "maybe" it uses Trie, but i want a definite answer, Can anyone please answer it??

Comment: I would really appreciate if somebody explains(a bit) about the algorithm it uses,

Comment: Eclipse is open source. You could always take a look at the code yourself ;-)

Comment: Indeed, it's rather complex, and I'm not sure whether it is possible to summarize it in an answer that is adequate here (given that the question in its current form is rather broad). You may start reading at http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/plain/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/text/java/JavaCompletionProposalComputer.java and see whether you can find pointers to the parts that are relevant (or of interest) for you.

Answer (score -1):

There are different [Token-Scanners](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Ftext%2Frules%2FRuleBasedScanner.html) who search for known tokens like `{` and `;` to colorize the current *viewport-scopes* and fill a *history*. If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Spc</kbd> it looks backward and search for occourences in the *history*.